# How to build various pyinstaller binary versions with one code

Tags: jenkins, deployment, pyinstaller, cython

I have the .pyx file that has key string in its code.
Key string must be changed for their own version like real, alpha, beta and so on.

So, I want to change the "Key string" belongs to version when building process.

How can I do this within below process? (Using Jenkins for building the code.)

1. Make .so file with cython build
2. Make binary file with pyinstaller

I guess, use the "Active Choices parameter" in Jenkins is required to do this, if it is right then guide me how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this like below.

1. Create key storage directory.
2. Store the various key strings to it.
3. Use build scenario, and copy the specific key file.
4. Use `--add-file` option with `pyinstaller`, and modify a code that use the file.